# What does " 飲まずにはいられなかった" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

> 私が部屋に入ったとき彼は水を飲んでいた。その顔の蒼さが、水を**飲まずにはいられなかった**ことを示していた。

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3925/9831

Answer (score 0):

literally: not doing 飲む, cannot exist.

https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-zuniwa-irarenai/