# Categorizing kanji variants - is there a "proper" form?

Tags: kanji

Here are kanji variants:

- 海 (as an image: [image])
- 海

In case it does not display correctly for you, [the first *kanji* is unicode U+FA45.](http://glyphwiki.org/wiki/ufa45)

Is `海` considered a variant of the much more common `海`? Or, are `海` and `海` just considered mutual variants of each other?

More broadly, do you say that the most frequently used version of a *kanji* with a variant is "the" kanji? And that the kanji that is much less frequently used is the variant?

Also: What about rare cases such as `才` and `歳`, both of which are very frequently used?

Comment: In Japanese, 海 (with two dots) is considered an old variant, whereas 海 is the (current) standard.

Comment: I think that's mostly opinion-based, like the situation with dialects: Is there a Standard (Japanese/English/German/...) and dialects of it; or are they all just dialects? Fact is that 海 is *a lot* more common, and that it would look funny if you used the variant form without a reason. For that reason, you might consider it "the"  (proper) kanji (form), but imo that is non-objective.

Comment: I think for most of them they are simplified Chinese versus non-simplified.  Current standards in Japanese are the simplified ones.  Take that w/ a grain of salt, but also feel free to post a counter example. ;)

Comment: ＠kiss-o-matic No, Japanese is closer to traditional than simplified Chinese, but it has its own set of simplifications, so that's a bit of a red herring. @blutorange That's a false dichotomy.  Standard dialects are still dialects.

Comment: Regarding 才 and 歳, you might also refer to this question [Which is the “official” kanji for さい, 歳 or 才?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/which-is-the-official-kanji-for-%E3%81%95%E3%81%84-%E6%AD%B3-or-%E6%89%8D).

Comment: Anybody knows why various fonts insiste on using 海 instead of 海? Android's default system font does this, and most fonts on OS X too.  If 海 is the old variant, why aren't they all using 海?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Japanese Ministry of Education has published a list of kanji. I think this is the official document: 
http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/pdf/jouyoukanjihyou_h22.pdf

The "proper" form is whatever form is in that document. So the answer is basically that the government determines the "proper" form.